# header:location returning true statement on screen instead of redirecting

Tags: php

I have an online form that uses the POST method to create a url for a 3rd party payment system.

I can successfully generate the URL but instead of redirecting the browser is printing a statement on the screen:
True https://au.ewaygateway.com/PaymentPage.aspx?value=Cy2oFdkOUSyL5Iu8Ui1fPzBDdaFxyr1D9VCun21aAuexxxxxx

```
<?php
$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['ceml']));
$amt = trim(strip_tags($_POST['amt']));
$inv = trim(strip_tags($_POST['ord']));
header('location:https://au.ewaygateway.com/Request/?CustomerID=88888888&UserName=email@email.com&Amount='.$_POST["amt"].'&Currency=AUD&CustomerEmail='.$_POST["email"].'&ReturnUrl=http://www.domain.com.au/thank/&CancelUrl=http://www.domain.com.au&MerchantInvoice='.$_POST["inv"].''); 
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I think my problem is that the payment system is returning a true result and generating a new url to redirect to upon success - but i don't know how to take that result and redirect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my localserver, it is properly redirecting to ewgateaway and returns FalseMissing Required Field: Amount; Amount is not valid as variables are not set; from the ewgateaway website as the variables are not set. Code is working as expected.

Comment: ewaygateway.com is returning the error, probably validation error of some sort is causing it. check their documentation if you have missed something. code appears to be ok, unless i have missed something.